# CSS: Caracter dentro de um elemento redondo

Tags: css, css3, css-border-radius

Preciso criar um elemento (span, possivelmente) que conterá um carácter (letra inicial do nome) e esse elemento precisa ter os cantos arredondados.

Consegui fazer de forma precária, pois a depender a letra, a forma do elemento deixa de ser um redondo exato. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Abaixo, um exemplo do que preciso.

[image: Exemplo de como deve ficar a letra/elemento]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.circle
    {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:25px;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#580000 
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle">S</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, @psNytrancez! Exatamente o que precisava. Obrigado!

Comment: @DaniloMiguel valeu!!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.borderRadiu{
    border-radius: 5em;
    background: #660000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="borderRadiu">S</span>
```

Comment: -1? gostaria de entender a explicação.